# Is there a way to select a TextBox input if a checkbox is ticked? VBA Excel

Tags: vba, checkbox, userform

As you can see in the below image, I have several checkboxes representing measures and the last two are supposed allow for additional measures. The textboxes on the front allow the user to specify the name of their measure.

[image]

I was able to successfully send the name (caption) of the ticked checkboxes to a Listbox using the following code:

```
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctrl.Value = True Then
            ListBox1.AddItem ctrl.Caption
        End If
    End If
Next ctrl
```

However, if the user selects the "Additional measures" checkbox I want what they inputted in the textboxes to be added to the list box, instead of the checkbox caption.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Add an `if ctrl.name="whatever" then ListBox1.AddItem ctrl.value`.

Comment: @SJR, I tried that but it's not working.

Comment: Yes, sorry that's not right, you need to reference the textbox value.

Comment: So if the checkbox and textbox names are related that will make it simpler, otherwise you need more Ifs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the code simple, you may want work with `Tag`s instead of `Caption`s

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
            If ctl.Value And ctl.Tag <> "" Then
                ListBox1.AddItem ctl.Tag
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Me.CheckBox4.Tag = Me.TextBox1.Text
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Me.CheckBox5.Tag = Me.TextBox2.Text
End Sub
```

**Edit:** Added the condition `And ctl.Tag <> ""`

Answer (score 0):

So I tried using more if statements as SJR suggested and it worked.

```
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctrl.Value = True Then
            If ctrl.Caption = "Additional Metric 1 (Specify Metric)" Then
                ListBox1.AddItem TextBox3.Value
            ElseIf TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
                If ctrl.Value = True Then
                    If ctrl.Caption = "Additional Metric 2 (Specify Metric)" Then
                        ListBox1.AddItem TextBox4.Value
        Else
            ListBox1.AddItem ctrl.Caption
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next ctrl
```

Is there any way to simplify this? :)

Comment: You don't need the `ElseIf TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then` line.  It will always return true because you already checked that it's a checkbox in the first If statement.  You also need the second `If ctrl.Value = True Then` line because that will also always evaluate as true.